# Data structure options for efficiently storing sets of integer pairs on disk?

Tags: python, c, data-structures, integer

I have a bunch of code that deals with document clustering.  One step involves calculating the similarity (for some unimportant definition of "similar") of every document to every other document in a given corpus, and storing the similarities for later use.  The similarities are bucketed, and I don't care what the specific similarity is for purposes of my analysis, just what bucket it's in.  For example, if documents 15378 and 3278 are 52% similar, the ordered pair (3278, 15378) gets stored in the [0.5,0.6) bucket.  Documents sometimes get either added or removed from the corpus after initial analysis, so corresponding pairs get added to or removed from the buckets as needed.

I'm looking at strategies for storing these lists of ID pairs.  We found a SQL database (where most of our other data for this project lives) to be too slow and too large disk-space-wise for our purposes, so at the moment we store each bucket as a compressed list of integers on disk (originally zlib-compressed, but now using lz4 instead for speed).  Things I like about this:

- Reading and writing are both quite fast
- After-the-fact additions to the corpus are fairly straightforward to add (a bit less so for lz4 than for zlib because lz4 doesn't have a framing mechanism built in, but doable)
- At both write and read time, data can be streamed so it doesn't need to be held in memory all at once, which would be prohibitive given the size of our corpora

Things that kind of suck:

- Deletes are a huge pain, and basically involve streaming through all the buckets and writing out new ones that omit any pairs that contain the ID of a document that's been deleted
- I suspect I could still do better both in terms of speed and compactness with a more special-purpose data structure and/or compression strategy

So: what kinds of data structures should I be looking at?  I suspect that the right answer is some kind of exotic succinct data structure, but this isn't a space I know very well.  Also, if it matters: all of the document IDs are unsigned 32-bit ints, and the current code that handles this data is written in C, as Python extensions, so that's probably the general technology family we'll stick with if possible.

Answer (score 1):

How about using one hash table or B-tree per bucket?

On-disk hashtables are standard. Maybe the BerkeleyDB libraries (availabe in stock python) will work for you; but be advised that they since they come with transactions they can be slow, and may require some tuning. There are a number of choices: gdbm, tdb that you should all give a try. Just make sure you check out the API and initialize them with appropriate size. Some will not resize automatically, and if you feed them too much data their performance just drops a lot.

Anyway, you may want to use something even more low-level, without transactions, if you have a lot of changes.

A pair of ints is a long - and most databases should accept a long as a key; in fact many will accept arbitrary byte sequences as keys.

Comment: Hm, yeah, BDB is worth investigating, and something I didn't think about.  Any idea whether there's any potential for dealing with compressed data in BDB?  We find that the integer data compresses really nicely in general, so it keeps our ec2 bills down, though it's not a strict requirement.

Comment: I don't know about compressed hash tables. The problem is that usually for random access you want block oriented structures. You clearly can save a lot of memory in your case by using fixed size records (because you save the lenght information!). OTOH, if you have a lot of small integers, you may want to use variable length integer encodings anyway. But I doubt that BDB will support this out of the box, you may need to roll your own on-disk hash table structure for this. An optimized on-disk block format would probably be all varints: one for the count, then key, value varints.

Comment: Usually, databases are designed to handle large data, not huge amounts of integers. For such data, it may be reasonable to deploy an optimized structure, because it can easily cut down the IO by 2.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just store a table containing *stuff that was deleted since the last re-write*?

This table could be the same structure as your main bucket, maybe with a Bloom filter for quick membership checks.

You can re-write the main bucket data without the deleted items either when you were going to re-write it anyway for some other modification, or when the ratio of *deleted items:bucket size* exceeds some threshold.

---

This scheme could work either by storing each deleted pair alongside each bucket, or by storing a single table for all deleted documents: I'm not sure which is a better fit for your requirements.

Keeping a single table, it's hard to know when you can remove an item unless you know how many buckets it affects, without just re-writing *all* buckets whenever the deletion table gets too large. This could work, but it's a bit stop-the-world.

You also have to do two checks for each pair you stream in (ie, for `(3278, 15378)`, you'd check whether either `3278` or `15378` has been deleted, instead of just checking whether pair `(3278, 15378)` has been deleted.

Conversely, the per-bucket table of each deleted pair would take longer to build, but be slightly faster to check, and easier to collapse when re-writing the bucket.

Comment: This may well end up being the direction I go... deletes are much rarer than additions, so a table of deleted documents may well be the simplest.  Certainly, I don't think any of my corpora have had enough deletes that I couldn't easily hold all the deletes in memory as I streamed the buckets.

Comment: That said, if I were storing uncompressed data, I could just stream through the buckets and zero out pairs of which one had been deleted, which would also avoid the rewrite while not requiring the table, and which would be even better from my perspective.  I guess the holy grail that I was looking for was a compact representation of the data that would preserve that facility, but that may not actually exist, and this may well be the next best thing.

Comment: Sadly the Bloom filter is the closest I got to an exotic succinct data structure. Although more an optimisation than a functional change, it seems like a good fit.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to reinvent what already exists in new age NoSQL data stores.
There are 2 very good candidates for your requirements.

1. Redis.
2. MongoDb

Both support data structures like dictionaries,lists,queues. The operations like append, modify or delete are also available in both , and very fast.

The performance of both of them is driven by amount of data that can reside in the RAM.
Since  most of your data is integer based, that should not be a problem.

My personal suggestion is to go with Redis, with a good persistence configuration (i.e. the data should periodically be saved from RAM to disk ).

Here is a brief of redis data structures :
http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro

The redis database is a lightweight installation, and client is available in Python.

Comment: Other parts of my application use both Redis and MongoDB.  Neither is suitable for this purpose.  Redis can't handle data too large to fit in RAM -- mine does; I have individual corpora whose clustering data is multiple gigabytes of data compressed on disk, and about 150k corpora.  MongoDB is much too slow for my purposes.  I want something *faster* than what I have now, which is raw integers stored compressed on disk.

Comment: I also don't need the kind of availability that a database server provides.  I calculate the similarities, then pass those on to the next step in the pipeline, which is to use the similarities to do the actual clustering analysis, whose output is much smaller.  *That* lives in redis, since it gets used by a web application.  The similarity data will sit unused on disk until documents are added to or removed from the corpus, at which point they'll be re-analyzed and the clustering results in Redis updated.